# Jenkins Node on Redhat Windows Master jnlp file won't load

Tags: java, jenkins, rhel7

I have a Jenkins master on Windows server 2016 and a node on RHEL 7. When I try to connect from client to master using Java Web start the jnlp file is downloaded with no problems. The issue happens when javaws opens the file I get the following error : "com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource http://localhost:8080/jnlp.jars/remoting.jar" In the Java Console I used the proxy settings from the master which uses an automated .pac file. I have jdk 8 update 181  on both master and node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone with a similar issue on Stackoverflow. The issue is with the way the jnlp file gets edited on import and takes out the master hostname and inserts "localhost." Since the file obviously doesn't exist locally the jnlp load fails.